# How to Build curl with NDK 10rd in windows

Tags: android, windows, curl, build, android-ndk

I am new to NDK, Now I want to build curl with NDK 10rd in windows 7. I download curl's code at[https://github.com/bagder/curl].

I have tried and searched many ways. But It does not work.

The error info is :

```
E:/study/thrid_lib/curl-master//jni/src/setup.h:41:25: fatal error: curl_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "curl_config.h"
```

INFO:
My curl 's path is "E:/study/thrid_lib/curl-master/jni". 
Using cmd into this path and typing "ndk-build",then error will appear.

At last, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem.The details are below:

1. Put the curl(My curl's version is 7.42.1) into the **jni** folder.
2. Download the file(http://mtterra.com/files/curltest.tar.gz) and extracting it.
3. Copy the curl_config.h to the **curl/lib**.
4. Copy the Android.mk to the **jni** folder.
5. Run ndk-build in cmd.

That 's all. If you have anythings confused, feel free to contact me.

Comment: (http://mtterra.com/files/curltest.tar.gz) - does not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

The [*instructions*](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/docs/INSTALL#L845) explain how to cross-compile curl with a standalone toolchain.

As in many similar cases, you may find it easier to launch Linux in a VirtualBox and compile the library there, rather than to struggle with cygwin or mingw.